# how to apply a def function with 2 parameters into panda columns table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Would someone please let me know how to apply the function with 2 parameters into DataFrame? I have tried a lot of solution but still not successful. Here is my code below.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'tran_amt_lcy':[40,500,60],'tran_amt_usd':[30,40,50],'client_id':['2001','2033','2045']})

df.dtypes

def test_func(col1,col2):
    if col1>30 & col2<500:
        tran_status='approved'
    else:
        tran_status='declined'
    return tran_status

df['tran_stat']=df.apply(lambda x:test_func(df['tran_amt_usd'],df['tran_amt_lcy']),axis=1)
```

The error message still pop up as ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I don't know why it is still failed. Does anyone tell me the possible way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binary condition, you can use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np

# Boolean mask
m = (df['tran_amt_usd'] > 30) & (df['tran_amt_lcy'] < 500)
df['tran_stat'] = np.where(m, 'approved', 'declined')
print(df)

# Output
   tran_amt_lcy  tran_amt_usd client_id tran_stat
0            40            30      2001  declined
1           500            40      2033  declined
2            60            50      2045  approved
```

There are many post which explain this error. In fact, Python can't compare a list (or a Series) to a scalar value. In your case, you try to evaluate:

```
([30, 40, 50] > 30) & ([40, 500, 60] < 100)
```

**Update**

> Do this with a def function

```
def test_func(col1, col2):
    m = (col1 > 30) & (col2 < 500)
    return np.where(m, 'approved', 'declined')

# You don't need apply here
df['tran_stat'] = test_func(df['tran_amt_usd'], df['tran_amt_lcy'])
```

Comment: but if i wanna to do this with a def function, is it possible to do ?

Comment: @TonyTang. I updated my answer, can you check it please? Try to use vectorization and avoid apply.